# Npm wouldn't compile dev/prod and freezing at url-resolver

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix

```
69% building 804/805 modules 1 active ...w/xxxxxx/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--5-4!/var/www/xxxxxx/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!/var/www/xxxxxx/resources/sass/laraspace.scss
```

How to debug why it's freezing at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this in webpack config helped me:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js/').options({
    processCssUrls: false
})
```

seems webpack was updated and something change by default